# Hide / Unhide com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout when software keyboard is Open / Close in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm using com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout for designing of my fragment.
I want to hide the sliding panel when the software keyboard is opened and want to unhide it when software keyboard is closed.
How to do this programatically?

For layout of fragment containing com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout I've written code as

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/prescription_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:gravity="bottom"
sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
sothree:umanoOverlay="false"
sothree:umanoPanelHeight="150dp"
sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="150dp"
sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/list"
sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:focusable="false">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="280dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried googling this, first?

Comment: Yes. I've tried googling this, But there is no specific solution for checking (getting event for) hide or unhide software keyboard.
Everything we've to do pragmatically. But I'm not getting the code with which i can check whether  software keyboard is open or not.

Comment: In some code i got the Event for software keyboard in which they are checking for rootView Size (Size of Root Layout of Fragment). If the size is resized with more than 100 pixel then keyboard is open. But in that case slideUpLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); does not work well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for that. In Manifest file android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" doesn't work for this View .

But when you wrap this d@mn view with a LinearLayout, like here

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout >
      ...
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout >
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in a Manifest file property 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" 
works like a charm. 
And panel is not shown on the top of a soft Keyboard.